# How to build a custom LXD image from install ISO

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, lxc, containers

I have an operating system installation ISO.
My goal is to run the second operating system on top of the kernel of Ubuntu host running LXD. I cannot find any base image for the said operating system. Is it possible for me to build a custom lxc image to run on top of ubuntu kernel and access the shell of the second system?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I am not totally clear on what exactly you are trying to achieve here - could you expand on your use case a little, for example by explaining what the sequence of events should be? I am struggling a little to understand what you mean precisely by `second operating system` - on the face of it, that sounds like you need (para)virtualisation, rather than containers. For building LXC base images, have you tried `lxc-create`,?Ubuntu's [LXC overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html) gives some instructions

Answer (score 2):

Stéphane Graber described the procedure for creating images for LXD 2.0 and above from scratch in the article [LXD 2.0: Image management](https://stgraber.org/2016/03/30/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/) (section *"Manually building an image"*):

> ### Manually building an image
>
> Building your own image is also pretty simple.
>
> 1. Generate a container filesystem. This entirely depends on the distribution you’re using. For Ubuntu and Debian, it would be by using `debootstrap`.
> 2. Configure anything that’s needed for the distribution to work properly in a container (if anything is needed).
> 3. Make a tarball of that container filesystem, optionally compress it.
> 4. Write a new `metadata.yaml` file based on the one described above.
> 5. Create another tarball containing that `metadata.yaml` file.
> 6. Import those two tarballs as a LXD image with:
>
>    ```
>    lxc image import <metadata tarball> <rootfs tarball> --alias some-name
>    ```
>
> You will probably need to go through this a few times before everything works, tweaking things here and there, possibly adding some templates and properties.

The file `metadata.yaml` must contain at least the following two key/value pairs (replace `i686` with the correct system architecture and `1458040200` with the timestamp in Unix epoch format (e.g. `date +%s`):

```yaml
architecture: "i686"
creation_date: 1458040200
```

Further information about the `metadata.yaml` can be found in the abovementioned article (section *"Image metadata"*).

Comment: And where do I find doco that describes ` tweaking things here and there, possibly adding some templates and properties.` ? I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to wedge my templates in there somehow.

Comment: Which part of *"Further information about the `metadata.yaml` can be found in the abovementioned article (section "Image metadata")"* requires further explanation? Click the link in my answer. Go to the section "Image metadata". Scroll down a bit until you get to the sub-section "Templates". Start reading.

Comment: Heh. Ta. I have read that page at least ten times in the last 7 days; doesn't mention anywhere how one ties templates into the tar-ball before importing it into lxd ... did more experimentation though, and figured it out eventually. `lxd` doco is notoriously errrrrh `terse`, `incomplete` :D

Comment: The parent section of "Image metadata" ("Image formats") features a link to [this little gem](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/image-handling.md).

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 I was using Hashicorp Packer to build custom **LXD** images (but it stopped working) - so I wrote & recently released:

- [distrobuilder-menu](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu) - a python console frontend to Distrobuilder

install as an isolated app with:

- `pipx install distrobuilder-menu`

The [README on Github](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/README.md) will always be the latest version & should be enough to get most users up to speed.

[Features](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu#%EF%B8%8F-features)

- Standard templates updated via the Github REST API
- Custom templates are automatically re-generated when standard templates are updated (so they never become outdated)
- LXD & it's new fork `incus` are both supported
- Custom **LXD** & **LXC** images can be built